# How to match the first word after an expression with regex?

Tags: regex, lookbehind, word-boundary

For example, in this text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu tellus vel nunc pretium lacinia. Proin sed lorem. Cras sed ipsum. Nunc a libero quis risus sollicitudin imperdiet.

I want to match the word after 'ipsum'.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This sounds like a job for lookbehinds, though you should be aware that not all regex flavors support them. In your example:

```
(?<=\bipsum\s)(\w+)
```

This will match any sequence of letter characters which follows "ipsum" as a whole word followed by a space. It does **not** match "ipsum" itself, you don't need to worry about reinserting it in the case of, e.g. replacements.

As I said, though, some flavors (JavaScript, for example) don't support lookbehind at all. Many others (most, in fact) only support "fixed width" lookbehinds — so you could use this example but not any of the repetition operators.  (In other words, `(?<=\b\w+\s+)(\w+)` *wouldn't* work.)

Comment: Lookbehinds tend to be pretty limited when it comes to using wildcards though.

Comment: Lookbehinds might not even be necessary here. Depending on what 'I want to match' in the question refers to, see David Kemp's solution.

Comment: zero-width tends to be what you want though, it's just that grouping is a trivial get out of jail card.

Comment: Fixed width is a misleading term - it is more "max width", yes? In most cases it is possible to use a suitable limit, for example: (?<=\b\w{1,100}\s{1,100})

Comment: @Peter — No, it really is *fixed* width. Try your regex there in Python; it throws an exception.

Comment: I think I have discovered a way to circumvent the fixed width lookbehind restriction in some flavours of regex in some cases. Say you want to find B but only if it isn't preceded by A and any number of spaces. In most flavours of regex you wouldn't be able to use `(?<!A *)(B)` since the lookbehind isn't fixed. Instead you could use `^(?>(?>(?>(?>(?!A *B).)*)A *B)*).*?(B)` Note that this can get very inefficient if the flavour does not also support atomic grouping or possessive quantifiers...

Answer (score 6):

Some of the other responders have suggested using a regex that doesn't depend on lookbehinds, but I think a complete, working example is needed to get the point across.  The idea is that you match the whole sequence ("ipsum" plus the next word) in the normal way, then use a capturing group to isolate the part that interests you.  For example:

```
String s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur " +
    "adipiscing elit. Nunc eu tellus vel nunc pretium " +
    "lacinia. Proin sed lorem. Cras sed ipsum. Nunc " +
    "a libero quis risus sollicitudin imperdiet.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ipsum\\W+(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
{
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Note that this prints both "dolor" and "Nunc".  To do that with the lookbehind version, you would have to do something hackish like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=ipsum\\W{1,2})(\\w+)");
```

That's in Java, which requires the lookbehind to have an obvious maximum length.  Some flavors don't have even that much flexibility, and of course, some don't support lookbehinds at all.

However, the biggest problem people seem to be having in their examples is not with lookbehinds, but with word boundaries.  Both David Kemp and ck seem to expect `\b` to match the space character following the 'm', but it doesn't; it matches the position (or boundary) *between* the 'm' and the space.

It's a common mistake, one I've even seen repeated in a few books and tutorials, but the word-boundary construct, `\b`, never matches any characters.  It's a zero-width assertion, like lookarounds and anchors (`^`, `$`, `\z`, etc.), and what it matches is a position that is either preceded by a word character and not followed by one, or followed by a word character and not preceded by one.

Answer (score 2):

ipsum\b(\w*)

Comment: That seems to only match ipsum.

Comment: I'd probably make that \b+(\w+) at least

Comment: ipsum\b+(\w+) is not valid regex.

Comment: @Matthew Taylor: It depends on your platform. You didn't specify which platform/language you're using.

Comment: I see.  I'm using Java regex on OS X.

Comment: \b+ matches one or more word boundaries, which makes no sense because a word boundary has zero length. Some flavors will ignore the + but others will reject it as an error. I think "ipsum\s+(\w+)" is what you're groping for.

Answer (score 1):

With `javascript` you can use `(?=ipsum.*?(\w+))`

This will get the second occurrence as well (Nunc)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\bipsum\s|\bipsum\.\s)(\w+)
```

`/(?<=\bipsum\s|\bipsum\.\s)(\w+)/gm`
**Positive Lookbehind** `(?<=\bipsum\s|\bipsum\.\s)`
Assert that the Regex below matches

1. *1st Alternative* `\bipsum\s`
   \b assert position at a word boundary: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
   ipsum matches the characters ipsum literally (case sensitive)
   \s matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
2. *2nd Alternative* `\bipsum\.\s`
   \b assert position at a word boundary: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
   ipsum matches the characters ipsum literally (case sensitive)
   . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
   \s matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
   1st Capturing Group (\w+)
   \w+ matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

- Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  Global pattern flags
  g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
  m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Answer (score 0):

Example statement: "availebleLimit: Double?". İf you want to find words after ':' character, the below regex can be used

Regex => :.+$

Answer (score -1):

ipsum\b(.*)\b

EDIT: 
although depending on your regex implementation, this could be hungry and find all words after ipsum

Comment: That'll match the rest of the sentence.

Comment: you have to make that ungreedy

Comment: Actually it's not implementation dependent, or at least I've never come across a regex implementation that is non-greedy by default.  Non-greedy is always a switch (at least in Perl, PHP, Java and .Net).

Comment: @cletus: regex implementation can by definition include passing switches to the call to the regex function

Comment: Yes but they all default to greedy and you pass in switches to turn that off (although PHP has a switch to invert the behaviour of *? and +? to being greedy while * and + become non-greedy).  Still, that's a switch from the default.

Comment: Even if you make it non-greedy--ie, "ipsum\b(.*?)\b"--it still won't work. The "(.*?)" will just match the space between 'ipsum' and the next word.