# Regex / Yahoo Pipes - Match first word after an expression

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I'm basically trying to do the same thing as in this example - [How to match the first word after an expression with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546220/regex-how-to-match-the-first-word-after-an-expression) - but within Yahoo Pipes.

I've tested the answered coded in Yahoo Pipes but it doesn't seem to be do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo's documentation](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=string#StringRegex) mentions capture groups are supported.

So you could likely use the String Regex module to e.g. replace `ipsum (\w+)` with `$1`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little lost. How would I find the next word rather than replace ipsum?