# Get next word after preg match with PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I get the next word after pregmatch with PHP.

For example, If I have a string like this:

```
"This is a string, keyword next, some more text. keyword next-word."
```

I want to use a `preg_match` to get the next word after “keyword”, including if the word is hyphenated.

So in the case above, I want to return “next” and ”next-word”

I’ve tried :

```
$string = "This is a string, keyword next, some more text. keyword next-word.";

$keywords = preg_split("/(?<=\keyword\s)(\w+)/", $string);
print_r($keywords);
```

Which just returns everything and doesn’t seem to work at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `strpos` gives you where something shows up and makes it easy to find the point afterwards.

Comment: strpos only returns the first occurrence though. I want to push everything to an array

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  My regex experience doesn't know the `<=` part of the regex you provided, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your example this should work using [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
// Set the test string.
$string = "This is a string, keyword next, some more text. keyword next-word. keyword another_word. Okay, keyword do-rae-mi-fa_so_la.";

// Set the regex.
$regex = '/(?<=\bkeyword\s)(?:[\w-]+)/is';

// Run the regex with preg_match_all.
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

// Dump the resulst for testing.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the results I get are:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => next
            [1] => next-word
            [2] => another_word
            [3] => do-rae-mi-fa_so_la
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow that's super nice! Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: You can remove `_` from the character class, the non capturing group and the s modifier.

Comment: Nice, I did it as preg_match instead of preg_match_all and used echo $matches{0] to show the first word after $regex = '/(?<=\b'.$var.'\s)(?:[\w-]+)/is';  -- Needed this script. Ty for the code

Answer (score 0):

Positive look behind is what you are looking for:

```
(?<=\bkeyword\s)([a-zA-Z-]+)
```

Should work perfect with `preg_match`. Use `g` modifier to catch all matches.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nB9rU1)

Reference Question: [How to match the first word after an expression with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546220/how-to-match-the-first-word-after-an-expression-with-regex)

Answer (score 0):

While regex is powerful, it's also for most of us hard to debug and memorize.

On this particular case, **Get next word after ... match with PHP**, which is a very common string operation.

Simply, by exploding the string in an array, and searching the index. This is useful because we can specify how much words forward or backward.

This match the first occurrence + `1 word`:

```
<?php
$string = explode(" ","This is a string, keyword next, some more text. keyword next-word.");
echo $string[array_search("keyword",$string) + 1];
/* OUTPUT next, *
```

[Run it online](https://3v4l.org/4bnXr)

By reversing the array, we can catch the last occurrence - `1 word`:

```
<?php
$string = array_reverse(explode(" ","This is a string, keyword next, some more text. keyword next-word."));
echo $string[array_search("keyword",$string) - 1];
/* OUTPUT next-word. */
```

[Run it online](https://3v4l.org/4o4FJ)

This is good for performances if we are making multiples searches, but of course the length of the **string must be kept short** (whole string in memory).